# ASM Bytecode to identify for / while loops

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

Using ASM Bytecode Can we identify for loops or while loops present in the method body?

Comment: Your tags don't make sense.

Comment: So you want somthing like "if byte xyz is there, is it a while loop"?

Comment: hi deviantfan , you are right.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which information you want to extract. In principle, you can detect loops by searching for *backward branches*. A loop can’t work without and with usual code structures you won’t find backward branches which are not part of a loop.

So if you want to have them named explicitly, all of the bytecode instructions `goto`, `goto_w`, `if_acmpeq`, `if_acmpne`, `if_icmpeq`, `if_icmpge`, `if_icmpgt`, `if_icmple`, `if_icmplt`, `if_icmpne`, `ifeq`, `ifge`, `ifgt`, `ifle`, `iflt`, `ifne`, `ifnonnull`, `ifnull` may indicate a loop if they point backwards.

But in most cases you will have a hard time telling what kind of loop you have. There is no significant difference between a `for` loop and a `while` loop in the compiled code. E.g., the following code fragments are entirely equivalent:

- ```
  for(a();b();c()) {
    d();
  }
  ```
- ```
  a();
  for(;b();) {
    d();
    c();
  }
  ```
- ```
  a();
  for(;;) {
    if(!b()) break;
    d();
    c();
  }
  ```
- ```
  a();
  while(b()) {
    d();
    c();
  }
  ```

It will become even worse with more complicated structure, e.g. when you want to find out whether two backward branches pointing to the same code location belong to a single loop with a conditional `continue` statement within the body or to two nested loops. It can turn out to be impossible.